# java runtime exec a python script with raw_input

Tags: java, python, exec, raw-input

I have a java program that runs a python script (The script is not mine and so cannot be changed).
I'm running the script with:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myScript.py");
```

The script has a "raw_input" line that expects the user input.
I tried using

```
BufferedWriter userInput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
userInput.write("myInput");
```

But that doesn't seem to work;

Another thing, I'm reading the output with

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
List<String> output = new ArrayList();
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                output.add(s);
            }
```

This works when the python script is not expecting any input, but when there's an input_raw(), the stdInput.readLine() is just stuck.

An example of the python script:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "your name is "+name
```

The whole program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    PythonRunner pr = new PythonRunner();

    pr.start();

    while(!pr.isFinished){
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting...");
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    for(String s:pr.result) System.out.println(s);
}

public class PythonRunner extends Thread {

public List<String> result;
public boolean isFinished;

public PythonRunner() {
    result= new ArrayList<>();
    isFinished = false;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myScript.py");

        BufferedWriter userInput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        userInput.write("myInput");

        String s;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
             result.add(s);
        }

        isFinished=true;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        isFinished=true;
    }

}
}
```

**EDIT:**
I managed to give the script the input using

```
userInput.write(cmd);
userInput.newLine();
userInput.flush();
```

However, I'm still having trouble reading the output. Some of the scripts have an infinite loop of input-> print.
for example, the script:

```
stop = False
while not stop:
    name = raw_input("")
    print "your name is "+name
    if name == "stop":
        stop = True
```

While this script runs, I can't seem to be able to read the output of the already given names.. Only when the process is given the "stop" command, can I read the whole output.

Comment: Perhaps adding a newline to the input would be enough. `"myInput\n"`. Python is reading a line... you need to supply a line.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference... I tried with "\n" and "\r" just to be on the safe side, but either one (nor both) seem to do anything. Calling userInput.newLine() also doesn't solve it..

Comment: I'm not a java guy, but my next steps would be to try closing the stream after the write. Perhaps a flush would be enough, but generally, a child stdin should be closed as soon as you are done with it. That saves you from programs that re-enter a stdin read loop and need to see EOF to be done with it.

Comment: Doing the input and then userInput.newLine; userInput.flush() worked. But if the script has a loop in it, then stdInput.readLine() still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inherit IO

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()

> Sets the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the
>   same as those of the current Java process. This is a convenience
>   method. An invocation of the form
>
> ```
> pb.inheritIO()
> ```

Then, your Process execution can take following form

```
public class ProcessSample {
 public static void main(String [] arg) throws Exception {
   ProcessBuilder pb =
      new ProcessBuilder("python", "script.py").inheritIO();
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
  }
}
```

and, with your script

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "your name is "+name
```

you can do

```
> javac ProcessSample.java
> java -cp . ProcessSample
What is your name? a
your name is a
```

**Inheriting IO for stdout**

You can always pass some values to Python code while at the same time read values from stdout - by inheriting it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class PythonProcessRedirect {

  public static void main(String [] arg) throws Exception {

    ProcessBuilder pb =
      new ProcessBuilder("python", "script_raw.py");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( p.getOutputStream() ));
    String input = "2\n";
    writer.write(input);
    writer.flush();

    p.waitFor();
  }
}
```

Note that for continuous flow of data you need to flush it

```
import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write("give some input: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
line = sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write("you typed: " + line)
sys.stdout.flush();
```

otherwise, data will be available not sooner than Python flushes it (e.g. by filling buffer up to the limit).

**Stream Gobbler**

You can also go with Stream Gobbler and run separate threads for stdin/stdout/stderr.

```
import java.io.*;

public class PythonProcessStreamGobblerIO {

  public static void main(String [] arg) throws Exception {

    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python ./script_os.py" );

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( p.getOutputStream() ));
          String input = "2\n";
          writer.write(input);
          writer.flush();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());  
          int data = -1;
          while((data =reader.read())!= -1){
            char c = (char) data;
            System.out.print(c);
          }
          reader.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }.start();

    p.waitFor();
  }
}
```

But, again, you have to make sure (on Python side) that stdout is flushed.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. This way, the user has to run the java program and type his input. That's not my goal. I already have the input (In the example - "myInput") in the example, and I need the program to automatically give it to the python script.

Comment: The flush was indeed the problem. I ended up running Python -u and that solved it.